# Nested Loop Tracing

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures, nested-loops, trace

I am having problems tracing this set of nested loop code. These are my workings.

- Goes to `def f1(a):`
- Goes to `a = f1(1)`
- Becomes `f1(f1(1))`
- Leave `f1` out first and solve `f1(1)` first
- `f1(1)` returns `f2`
- Goes into `def f2(b)` which is `f2(1)` now, so the parameter in `f2`
  is now `1`
- And I am lost.

  ```
    def f1(a):
       def f2(b):
         return a + b
       return f2

       a = f1(1)
       b = f1(100)

       print (a(2))
       print (b(2))
  ```

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: @andrew_reece I think OP wants an explanation of the code written there

Comment: You can use `pdb`, the python debugger, in case you want to follow what is going on.

Comment: Do you understand now?

Comment: Check out this:
For `Print(a(2))`
--> `f1(1)(2)`
--> `f2(2)`
-->`1+2`
-->`3`

For `Print(b(2))`
--> `f1(100)(2)`
--> `f2(2)`
--> `100 + 2`
--> `102`

Comment: Yes I do, thank you all of you

Comment: If you click the checkmark beside an answer below you'll mark it as accepted for future readers to know it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want an explanation of your code.

Let's start with

```
a = f1(1)
```

This is returning a f2 definition as an object with a value of `a = 1` in its scope.

```
b = f1(100)
```

This is the same as above, just now `a = 100` for this instance's scope.

Finally, with

```
print (a(2))
print (b(2))
```

You're passing the value `b = 2` to your two functions you saved above and evaluating them to get 3 and 102 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

For `Print(a(2))`

--> `f1(1)(2)`

--> `f2(2)`

-->`1+2`

-->`3`

For `Print(b(2))`

--> `f1(100)(2)`

--> `f2(2)`

--> `100 + 2`

--> `102`